# Swing vertical Navigation Menu

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I am creating desktop application and design using Swing. i have two panels in frame left and right panel, In the left panel I have buttons, So i want that when i click on button from left panel it should display the result in right panel on same frame. Does i need to create another frame with same left panel and create a right panel for the link , or there is a way for above written method have no idea that how to do this. Like Shown in below Image.

[image: Swing Menu]

Comment: where is the code

Comment: Use the [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for right panel. The left panel you can make using the [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html)

Answer (score 5):

I'd lay it out like this (there are other ways as well).

### Logically

- `BorderLayout`

  1. `GridBagLayout` (`LINE_START`)

     - `GridLayout`

       1. Button 1
       2. Button 2
       3. Button 3
       4. Button 4
  2. `CardLayout` (`CENTER`)

     - card Panel 1
     - card Panel 2
     - card Panel 3
     - card Panel 4

### Visually

[image]

Comment: With Eclipse/WindowBuilder (2018-12/1.9.1) you have to add a `JPanel` to the area of the `BorderLayout` you want to use, otherwise the `GridBagLayout`/`CardLayout`overwrites it.